# Sphinx searchd error : failed to mmap file archive.sps': Cannot allocate memory (length=3127114752); NOT

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx, indexer

I am using `sphinx 2.2.2-id64-beta` on `mysql 5.5.31` The system is running Centos 6, 32-bit. The server has 8GB RAM where 7.8GB are utilized.

For a full text search on archived data tables, which contain 10,000,000 rows, the indexer creates a 3.0G archive.sps file.

When I search through it the following error is thrown:

```
preload: failed to map file `'/var/lib/sphinx/archive.sps'`: Cannot allocate memory
(length=3127114752); NOT
```

I tried using: `docinfo = extern,ondisk_attrs = 1` for `sql_field_string=details` without any luck.

Do I need to free 3GB of RAM for sphinx or is there any way I can work this out?

Comment: Are you using the released 2.2.2 or an earlier snapshot? Also , 7.8GB is actual used from the 8GB? because if that is true, it's a bit dangerous to play with so high memory usage.

Comment: Thanx for reply aditirex .. Yes i am useing the beta version of sphinx 2.2.2 and our mysql server on the machine use most of the RAM as there are lot of queries are running on the server for full text search..by the time i am trying to split the index file of sphinx .. but it will stuck while searchd trying to precach the index .. 
 .. working on the same now ..